# Overflow:auto is not working properly with flexbox

Tags: css

I can't get overflow to work properly on `.modal-body`. When the window is resized the element overflow it's parent `.modal` when scrollbars should appear.

I only want scrollbars on `.modal-body`

https://jsfiddle.net/qsawmxg8/3/

```
<div id="modal">
  <div class="modal">
    <div>
      <div class="modal-header">header (no scroll/fixed)</div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This element should scroll when overflow<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body<br>body
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-actions">actions (no scroll/fixed)</div>
  </div>
</div>

#modal{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    display:flex;
}

.modal{
    margin:auto;
    padding:20px;
    max-height:calc(100% - 40px);
    width:500px;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:stretch;
    background:#ddd;
}

.modal-header{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background:white;
}

.modal-body{
    overflow:auto;
    min-height:60px;
}

.modal-actions{
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:right;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add an `overflow` property on the `.modal` class. Set it to `auto`. That fixes it. You can also add a `max-height` property on the `.modal-body` to fix it, but I won't suggest it for it won't look good in larger screen heights.

Comment: I only want scroll on `.modal-body`

Comment: If that so, that's where you put an `overflow:auto`. Then set the others to `overflow:hidden`.